# Typescript invoke function from object index with generic type

Tags: typescript, generics, web

I'm trying to use generics in Typescript in a way that a generic parameter will be used as an index to call a function stored in an object.
The error I'm receiving is:

> [ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((variable: { insertId: number; }) => string) | ((variable: { updateId: number; value: string; }) => string) | ((variable: { deleteId: number; }) => string)' has no compatible call signatures. [2349]

or

> Argument of type 'QueryInput[T]' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ insertId: number; } & { updateId: number; value: string; } & { deleteId: number; }'.
>     Type '{ insertId: number; } | { updateId: number; value: string; } | { deleteId: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ insertId: number; } & { updateId: number; value: string; } & { deleteId: number; }'.
>       Type '{ insertId: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ insertId: number; } & { updateId: number; value: string; } & { deleteId: number; }'.
>         Type '{ insertId: number; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ updateId: number; value: string; }': updateId, value
>           Type 'QueryInput[T]' is not assignable to type '{ insertId: number; }'.
>             Type '{ insertId: number; } | { updateId: number; value: string; } | { deleteId: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ insertId: number; }'.
>               Property 'insertId' is missing in type '{ updateId: number; value: string; }' but required in type '{ insertId: number; }'.ts(2345)
>   App.tsx(7, 13): 'insertId' is declared here.
>   (parameter) variables: QueryInput[T]

Here's a sample code that replicates the issue:

```
type Query = "insert" | "update" | "delete";

interface QueryInput {
  insert: { insertId: number };
  update: { updateId: number; value: string };
  delete: { deleteId: number };
}

type QueryObject = { [T in Query]: (variable: QueryInput[T]) => string };

const queries: QueryObject = {
  insert: variable => "insert",
  update: ({ updateId, value }) => "update",
  delete: variable => "delete"
};

const getQuery = <T extends Query>(query: T, variables: QueryInput[T]) => {
  return queries[query](variables); // this line throws an error
}
```

It seems as if the Typescript engine cannot resolve the correct signature of the function - although there is definitely only 1 possible signature (the one returned from `queries[query]`).
It seems that `query` and `variables` are resolved correctly, and have the appropriate types.

Comment: It can't infer the type of `variables` because the value of `query` is only known at run-time. Therefore TypeScript can not infer what is `queries[query]` so it assumes it is all possible types, but then you declare that `variables` can be of only one of those types, and it doesn't know which one.

Comment: Like I wrote, query and variable *are* resolved correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a quick dirty solution to make it compile,

```
const getQuery = <T extends Query>(query: T, variables: QueryInput[T]) => {
  let v: any = variables;
  return queries[query](v); // this line doesnt throw an error
}
```

It's not ideal, but getQuery itself doesn't seem to ever have to change anyway.
And the usage of getQuery will still be typed as you wanted with this solution, only its implementation not.

Until you find a better solution..

Comment: It doesn't work either. It throws the same error but in runtime.

Comment: Thank you! I had to upgrade typescript (I had 3.2.4, 3.4.1 work) and your solution did the trick.